# Using Binary Search to find a value in an Array (Java)

Tags: java, search, binary

I need to use binary search to locate 45.3 in the array. Here's what I have so far.

```
public class Bsearch {
    public static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;

    public static int binarySearch(int[] a, int x) {
        int low = 0;
        int high = a.length - 1;
        int mid;
        while (low <= high) {
            mid = (low + high) / 2;
            if (a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0)
                low = mid + 1;
            else if (a[mid].compareTo(x) > 0)
                high = mid - 1;
            else
                return mid;
        }
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int SIZE = 6;
        int[] a = new Integer[SIZE] = { 10, -3, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5 };
        System.out.println("45.3 Found" + binarySearch(a, 45.3));
    }
}
```

All my errors seem to be stemming from this area-

```
    int [] a = new Integer [ SIZE ]={ 10,-3,5,24,45.3,10.5 };
    System.out.println("45.3 Found" +binarySearch(a, 45.3));
```

All this is new to me so sorry for any obvious mistakes.

Comment: which error?Please specify error

Comment: Why use floats in an Integer-array?

Comment: Why assign an `Integer[]` to a variable of type `int[]`? :-)

Comment: Java doesn't support "a[mid].compareTo(x) < 0". You may use "a[mid] < x " instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed in this line:

```
int[] a = new Integer[SIZE] = { 10, -3, 5, 24, 45.3, 10.5 };
```

There are a number of issues:

1. You can't assign an `Integer[]` to an `int[]` variable. Change it to `new int[]`
2. You can't put a floating point number in an array of integers; change your numbers 45.3 and 10.5 to integers.
3. You have two options in Java: when you create a new array with the `new` operator, you either specify size of the array, or the contents.

So either:

```
int[] a = new int[SIZE];
```

Or

```
int[] a = new int[] { 10, -3, 5, 24, 45, 10 };
```

Both will work.

---

You have to decide whether you want to use primitive types (`int`) of class wrappers (`Integer`) and stick to it.

Your method `binarySearch` takes an `int[]` as a parameter, but you are using methods (`compareTo`) that are only available on `Integer`.

But actually, comparing is much simpler with primitive types:

```
       if (a[mid] < x)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (a[mid] > x)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
```

Comment: now its giving me errors for the .compareTo parts? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For binary search Data Array should be sorted, and sorted in the right order, but the array you are passing to binarySearch(int[] a, int x) is not sorted so first sort the array and then apply binary search on it.
Also check your logic for binary search, you are comparing middle element with 0 it should be compared with the element to be searched(key)

```
while(high >= low) {
  int middle = (low + high) / 2;
  if(data[middle] == key) {
     return true;
  }
  if(data[middle] < key) {
  low = middle + 1;
  }
  if(data[middle] > key) {
  high = middle - 1;
  }
}
```